# "ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_from_path' from partially initialized module 'pdf2image' (most likely due to a circular import)"

Tags: python-3.x, image, pypdf

I am getting the error when using pdf2image module:

from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path('mypdf', 500)
for page in pages:
    page.save('out.jpg', 'JPEG')

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue, can you provide information on your pdf2image version, OS and specific PDF which causes this issue?

Comment: I am getting the error when using pdf2image module:convert_from_path
from pdf2image importconvert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path('mypdf', 500) 
for page in pages: 
 page.save('out.jpg', 'JPEG')

Comment: I can confirm that the code snippet you gave/pdf2image is not the source of your issue. You should check if you already have an import statement for `pdf2image` or `convert_from_path`.

Comment: how can I do that

Answer (score 14):

I'm going out on a limb and guessing your python file is called pdf2image.py. Try naming it something else.

Comment: lol this was me...thank you for obvious thing to miss

Comment: lmao same happened to me, im such a moron